# Why Visual Studio 2022 compiles c++ code with debug libraries in release mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-compiling, nvapi

I am trying to run a very small c++ program using the nvapi library on a different machine than it was compiled on. So it does not have the Visual Studio resources installed thus all the necessary things have to be packed inside the executable at build time. When the executable is being ran on the other windows machine it throws a runtime error stating that `“MSVCP140D.dll”` is missing. The “D” at the end of the file name indicates that it is a dev library even though I built with release mode. The build output is inside a “Release” folder which means Visual Studio uses the right build method. In `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library` is set to `Multi-threaded (/MT)`. Which logically should not link to dev libraries.

Comment: The 'D' stands for 'debug'. It's a debug version of the MSVC runtime library. Something in your project has a dependency on it. The correct way to distribute libraries with MSVC runtime dependency is to ship it with (or state the dependence on) the [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-140) installer for that version.

Comment: Are all the libraries you're linking to also built in release mode? Which runtime is your project set to? There's nothing stopping the release configuration being set to use the debug runtime

Comment: @paddy: Installing the runtime won't solve this, the debug libraries are not redistributable.

Comment: Presumably the nvapi library requires the debug libraries. If it's not your code that has the dependency then it is someone else's.

Comment: My project is set to use /MT and NOT /MTd. So if I understand correctly the nvapi library might have been built in debug mode by nvidia? If so do I have to rebuild it in release mode with release dependencies?

Comment: If you used /MT then you are not supposed to have any dependency on msvcp140.dll.  Clearly there something else that needs it, there's no reasonable guess from the provided info.  At least run dumpbin.exe /imports on any binary you deploy.

Answer (score -1):

Check which file in your build output is depending on the debug runtime. You can use a tool such as [this dependency viewer](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to find the offending library. If you load the exe file, you get the tree of dependencies, if you somewhere find the *d.dll files, you know the "bad guy".

(Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with that tool, but it's the one I've been using most. There are a bunch of other similar tools available)